Capture of 'self' with non-sendable type in a `@Sendable` closure
I'm working on a NetworkService class in Swift that uses async/await and observes network state changes. I'm converting the code to Swift 6.0 and I'm getting the following error on the line inside setupNetworkMonitoring():
Capture of 'self' with non-sendable type 'NetworkService' in a @Sendable closure

Here's my code:
public class NetworkService {
    
    private let session: URLSessionProtocol
    private let networkMonitor: NetworkMonitorProtocol
    private let stateSubject = CurrentValueSubject<NetworkActivityState, Never>(.idle)
    
    private var requestQueue: [URLRequest] = []
    
    @MainActor
    public init(session: URLSessionProtocol, networkMonitor: NetworkMonitorProtocol) {
        self.session = session
        self.networkMonitor = networkMonitor
        Task {
            await setupNetworkMonitoring()
        }
    }
    
    public func request(_ urlRequest: URLRequest) async throws -> Data? {
        // process url request or enqueue the request when the network state
        // is "offline"
        
    }
    
    // Monitor the network to handle requests when state changes
    private func setupNetworkMonitoring() async {
        await networkMonitor.startMonitoring { [weak self] state in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            Task {
                // ⬇ ⬇ ⬇ Capture of 'self' with non-sendable type 'NetworkService' in a `@Sendable` closure
                try await self.onNetworkStateChanged(networkConnectionState: state)
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Handle network state changes
    public func onNetworkStateChanged(networkConnectionState: NetworkConnectionState) async throws {
        switch networkConnectionState {
        case .connected where stateSubject.value == .waitingForConnection:
            try await executeQueuedRequests()
            stateSubject.send(NetworkActivityState.idle)
        case .offline, .restricted:
            stateSubject.send(NetworkActivityState.waitingForConnection)
        case .connected, .notDetermined:
            stateSubject.send(stateSubject.value)
        }
    }
    
    // When network state changes from "waitingForConnection" to "connected"
    // process any enqueued request
    private func executeQueuedRequests() async throws {
        for urlRequest in requestQueue {
            _ = try await request(urlRequest)
        }
        requestQueue.removeAll()
    }
}

This is what I tried:

make NetworkService conform to Sendable, but this leads to a cascade of changes as many of its dependencies also need to conform to Sendable.

using @MainActor on the class and relevant methods, but the error persists.

I've explored using a separate actor for handling network state changes, but I'm not sure if this a good solution as it adds a lot of boilerplate.


How can I resolve this concurrency issue without having to make NetworkService and all its dependencies conform to Sendable? I'm looking for a solution that maintains the overall structure of my NetworkService class while properly handling concurrency.
Any insights or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Can you give us mock classes for the values that you inject.

Just a thought or two: the requestQueue property is mutable, so simply making this conform to Sendable won't be good enough, I believe, as it actually is not sendable, even if you mark it as such. Also this property is currently not secured against data races. Maybe it would solve this problem and your sendable issue, if you'd make your NetworkService an actor, rather than a class?
